# Why if $aX+c=bX+d$ then $a=b$ and $c=d$?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

There is theorem in linear algebra. I forgot it!! But I remember something from it. Can you please give me a reference?

It is related to something like this. If I have two polynomials $P(X)=\alpha_pX^p+\alpha_{p-1}X^{p-1}+\dotsc+\alpha_0$ and $Q(X)=\beta_qX^q+\beta_{q-1}X^{q-1}+\dotsc+\beta_0$. If $P(X)=Q(X)$ and $p=q$ then $\alpha_p=\beta_q$, $\alpha_{p-1}=\beta_{q-1}$, $\dotsc$, $\alpha_0=\beta_0$. I remember something like this. Please can you give a name, reference?

Also with $\cos x$ and $\sin x$: $a\cos x+b\sin x=c\cos x+d\sin x$ then $a=c$ and $b=d$.

It is a theorem that is (I think) related to basis in vector space and something like this.

Comment: Technically, it should be $\forall x: P(x) = Q(x)$.  I would think it has something to with basis vectors (or basis functions in this case).  This is just something I've always taken for granted (but obviously somebody has proved it at some point).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this can be expressed in the language of linear algebra, as you seem to desire. Namely, over any infinite field $\,F\,$ the polynomials $\,\{X^i\}\,$ are basis of the polynomial function ring $\,K[X],\,$ hence $\ c+ aX = \langle c,a,0,0\ldots\rangle = \langle d,b,0,0\ldots\rangle = d+b X\,$ iff they have the same coefficients, i.e. $\, c=d,\, a=b.\,$

Similarly $\,\sin(x),\, \cos(x)\,$ are a basis for the solution space of of $\,y'' + y = 0\,$ (they are linearly independent by the Wronskian criterion) so an analogous statement holds.

**Remark** $\ $ This can fail over *finite* fields, e.g. by little Fermat $\,X^p = X\,$ as *functions* on $\,\Bbb F_p = \Bbb Z/p.\,$ However, it remains true for the ring of *formal* polynomials $\,R[x]\,$ (vs. polynomial *functions*), since, by definition, two *formal* polynomials are equal iff their corresponding coefficients are equal.

Answer (score 3):

Because the equality must hold for all values of $x$, if we let $x=0$ then we get $c=d $, then we let $x=1 $ to get $a+c=b +d$ but our previous findings give us that $a=b $. This generalises to polynomials of higher order, you just compare coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

[Fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) will help you with the first part: you have two polynomials that are identical on uncountable set (in particular, on $\Bbb R$): $$\forall X\in \Bbb R \quad P(X)=Q(X),$$
hence the difference of these polynomials must be zero (the difference has an uncountable set of zeroes), therefore, each coefficient in $P$ and $Q$ must coincide.

As for the second part, you can reformulate it as "$\cos x$ and $\sin x$" are linearly independent on $\Bbb R$. Indeed, let your equality hold for any $x\in \Bbb R$. Then you can choose $x=0$ to obtain $a=c$ and $x=\pi/2$ to obtain $b=d$.

Comment: The fundamental theorem of algebra has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @egreg care to elaborate? The theorem states `every non-zero, single-variable, degree` $n$ `polynomial with complex coefficients has, counted with multiplicity, exactly` $n$ `roots.` If we have more than $n$ roots, then the polynomial is identically zero and hence all its coefficients are zero.

Comment: This is a more basic result: a non zero polynomial can't have more roots than its degree. It follows by the fact that $a$ is a root of $f(X)$ if and only if $X-a$ divides $f(X)$. This statement is true in every integral domain, not only in algebraically closed fields.

Comment: @egreg still your previous comment (`has nothing to do with this`) is erroneous: fundamental theorem of algebra can be applied here and allows to conclude the necessary result.

Comment: You're wrong. The fundamental theorem of algebra says, more precisely, that a polynomial with *complex* coefficients has at least one root. The fact that the roots are as many as the degree of the polynomial is a consequence of the basic result I quoted.

Comment: @egreg If in your formulation the number of roots is omitted, it doesn't mean that other formulations don't exist. To give an example, read wiki article on this subject. A simple query in google returns quite a list of different sources where this theorem is given with the counting of zeroes. Anyway, if you're unable to accept that other formulations have their right to exist, then so be it.

Comment: You're applying it to ***the reals***, which can't be done. Can you see why? Indeed you're *only* using the fact that the number of roots can't exceed the degree and this has nothing to do with the FTA, because it holds in any field, algebraically closed or not.

Comment: @egreg real numbers are subset of complex numbers. As long as a complex polynomial has uncountable number of complex roots, it must be zero.

Comment: Let's cut it; you don't need *uncountable*, but just *infinite*. And you don't need the FTA: using a big gun to kill a mosquito is not good mathematics. I won't downvote your answer, but I want to make the OP aware of the flaws in it.

Comment: @egreg I agree with _infinite_ instead of _uncountable_. Usage of _big guns to kill a mosquito_ is a subjective question which has no clear answer. For me, as long as the job is done, all methods are good.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $a\neq b,c\neq d$. Then, we can write $a=b+D,c=d+E$. Then,
$$bX+DX+d+E=bX+d\\
\implies DX+E=0X+0$$
However, $E$ is constant, and not a function of $X$. Therefore, we need $E=0$, and similarly, we need $D=0$, showing that $a=b,c=d$.

Answer (score 1):

This is by definition: the polynomials $P(X)=\alpha_pX^p+\alpha_{p-1}X^{p-1}+\dots+\alpha_0$ and $Q(X)=\beta_qX^q+\beta_{q-1}X^{q-1}+\dots+\beta_0$ are equal *if and only if*
$$
p=q, \alpha_0=\beta_0, \alpha_1=\beta_1, \dots, \alpha_p=\beta_p.
$$
In the case of polynomials over an infinite field $F$, such as $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$, this is equivalent to
$$
\text{for all $a\in F$},\quad P(a)=Q(a)
$$
because in this case $P(X)-Q(X)$ would have infinitely many roots, which cannot be for a non zero polynomial (the converse is obvious). However, since polynomials over finite fields are really useful, for instance in studying error correcting codes or cryptography on elliptic curves, the other definition is preferred.

To see why one shouldn't rely on the identification with polynomial functions, consider a finite field $F=\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$ and the polynomial
$$
P(X)=(X-a_1)(X-a_2)\dots(X-a_n)
$$
which assumes the zero value for every element in $F$, but should definitely be considered non zero.

It's a different case for functions, where the definition is rightfully
$$
f=g\text{ if and only if }f(a)=g(a)\text{ for all $a$ in the common domain}.
$$
For the case of
$$
a\sin x+b\cos x=c\sin x+d\cos x
$$
just set $r=a-c$ and $s=b-d$, so you have to prove that, if
$$
r\sin x+s\cos x=0, \text{ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$}
$$
then $r=0$ and $s=0$. Simply choose $x=0$ and $x=\pi/2$, which gives
$$
\begin{cases}
0=r\sin0+s\cos0=s,\\
0=r\sin(\pi/2)+s\cos(\pi/2)=r.
\end{cases}
$$